# CSS Menu List and OnClick (active color)

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a menu from a tutorial I found online and I'm looking to take it one step further. I'd like to have each link completely change to the background color specified when it's clicked on. I tried using a:active but that didn't seem to work. Here's what I have so far, maybe I need to use some J-Query? Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDZ8F/) and code

```
<div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center; ">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a class="anchor" href="#welcomeanchor">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" href="#aboutusanchor">About Us </a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" href="#classesanchor">Classes </a> </li>
<li><a class="anchor" href="#scheduleanchor">Schedule</a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" href="#newsanchor">News</a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" href="#programsanchor">Programs</a></li>
<li><a class="anchor" href="#contactanchor">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

CSS

```
 #menu {
    width: 940px; 
    margin: 0 auto;}
    ul li {
    background:#000;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0;
    }
    ul li a {
    font-family: font3;
    width: 134px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 53px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #636393;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: .2s all linear;
    -moz-transition: .2s all linear;
    -o-transition: .2s all linear;
    transition: .2s all linear;
    }
    li:nth-child(1) a {
    border-color: #fff;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) a {
    border-color: #FF6;
    }
    li:nth-child(3) a {
    border-color: #F60;
    }
    li:nth-child(4) a {
    border-color: #00F;
    }
    li:nth-child(5) a {
    border-color: #0C6;
    }
    li:nth-child(6) a {
    border-color: #63C;
    }
    li:nth-child(7) a {
    border-color: #F00;
    }
    li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 55px solid #fff;
    height: 1px;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 55px solid #ff6;
    height: 1px; }
    li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 55px solid #f60;
    height: 1px; }
    li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 55px solid #00f;
    height: 1px; }
    li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 55px solid #0c6;
    height: 1px; }
    li:nth-child(6) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 55px solid #63c;
    height: 1px; }
    li:nth-child(7) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 55px solid #f00;
    height: 1px; }
```

Comment: use jquery -> when element is clicked add "active" class and then using css style the active class. FYI - this is different than "a:active" "a.active" is the selector to use for an active class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of had some fun with this.

**The jQuery Solution**

```
$('.anchor').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

You just need to add the active class to your css. http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/EDZ8F/7/

**The Pure CSS Solution**

Is a little more challenging and limited. I created an example of what you could do using the `:target` psudeo-class.

http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/EDZ8F/6/

*The HTML*

```
<div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center; ">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="welcomeanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#welcomeanchor">Home</a>
            <div><p>Home Content</p></div>     
        </li>
        <li id="aboutusanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#aboutusanchor">About Us </a>
             <div><p>About Us Content</p></div>
        </li>
        <li id="classesanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#classesanchor">Classes </a> 
            <div><p>Classes Content</p></div>
        </li>
        <li id="scheduleanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#scheduleanchor">Schedule</a>
            <div><p>Schedule Content</p></div>
        </li>
        <li id="newsanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#newsanchor">News</a>
            <div><p>News Content</p></div>
        </li>
        <li id="programsanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#programsanchor">Programs</a>
            <div><p>Programs Content</p></div>
        </li>
        <li id="contactanchor"><a class="anchor" href="#contactanchor">Contact</a>
            <div><p>Contact Content</p></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Relevant Changed CSS*

```
#menu li:not(:target) div{
    display: none;
}
#menu li div{
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
}
li:nth-child(1) a:hover, li:nth-child(1):target a {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 55px solid #fff;
    height: 1px;
}
li:nth-child(2) a:hover, li:nth-child(2):target a{
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 55px solid #ff6;
    height: 1px; 
}
li:nth-child(3) a:hover, li:nth-child(3):target a{
    border-bottom: 55px solid #f60;
    height: 1px; 
}
li:nth-child(4) a:hover, li:nth-child(4):target a{
    border-bottom: 55px solid #00f;
    height: 1px; 
}
li:nth-child(5) a:hover, li:nth-child(5):target a{
    border-bottom: 55px solid #0c6;
    height: 1px; 
}
li:nth-child(6) a:hover, li:nth-child(6):target a{
    border-bottom: 55px solid #63c;
    height: 1px; 
}
li:nth-child(7) a:hover, li:nth-child(7):target a{
    border-bottom: 55px solid #f00;
    height: 1px; 
}
```

Comment: I really like the way you did this! I'm going to use this method :)

Comment: where should the javascript be placed, does it matter if it's in the head or body?

Comment: I like to put all of my javascript right before the closing `</body>` tag. You can place your javascript anywhere you like though as long as you wrap it in a `$('document').ready()` http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: So you decided to go with the javascript method instead of the pure CSS solution?

Comment: I used yours. Is what's attached to your fiddle javascript or jquery? I don't know how to diffeientate between the two :D

Comment: You don't need to use any javascript or jquery if you are using the code in the fiddle. I have the javascript commented out just so you could reference it. All you need is the css and html to get it to work. I'll edit my answer to make this more clear. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34401/discussion-between-ovidio-borrero-and-blake-plumb)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

In Js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".anchor").click(function(){
       $(".anchor").each(function(){
          $(this).parent("li").css("background","#000")
       })
       var color1 = $(this).css("border-color");
       $(this).parent("li").css("background",color1);
    })
 })
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zM2mq/2/)

Comment: Great solution, I would add semi-colon's to the end of each function to be semantically correct.

Comment: This is perfect. The only thing that happens is for the White and Yellow links, the text color remains white and is hard to see, anyway to edit this to have those two list items appear black in color?

Comment: @Ovidio Borrero : I have update my FIDDLE so please check it out..!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify active to each element

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/EDZ8F/2/

```
li:nth-child(1) a:active {
color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(2) a:active {
color: #ff6;
}
li:nth-child(3) a:active {
    color:#f60;
}
li:nth-child(4) a:active {
    color:#00f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $('a.anchor');
$(a).click(function () {

    $(a).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EDZ8F/4/